# When use youtube-dl get direct link and download, how to rename the file?

Tags: youtube-dl

When I use youtube-dl to get the direct link like:

https://r1---sn-p5qs7n7d.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?XXXX....

And create a link for the user to download.

The download file always says videoplayback.mp4.

How to rename it to the video title ?

Answer (score 3):

° To get title and only that:

```
youtube-dl -e https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XA6bS8TyN10
```

Full name of `-e` option is `--get-title`. More informations, as always – in manual.

° To get direct link and only that:

```
youtube-dl --get-url https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XA6bS8TyN10
```

° To force filename used to download – you need to overwrite youtube's HTTP Content-Disposition. HTML5 offers `download` attribute for `a`, which is lovely, but actually is not working (in that case). If it be, code could looks like that:

```
<a download="saveAsThatFilename.mp4" href="url">foo</a>
```

But it's **not working** in that case. I guess you will not use any kind of proxy (which will be the simplest way, but not best of course). Then the good option is javascript.

Interesting option is [github: FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js).

I don't know how to solve it, but that's why I'll think about it. If you found solution – please, show it. There was few pretty similar questions ;)

Comment: This command will download to server.I want create a link in web page for user download.like <a href="https://r1---sn-p5qs7n7d.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?XXXX">donwload</a>

Comment: I've changed my answer. It's not solving all that problem, but maybe it'll be helpful.

Comment: I add &title=XXX in direct link and update youtube-dl , the problem seam to solve. But very thank for your answer.

Comment: Can you show example of url, which you generate with youtube-dl for 3gp or webm?

Answer (score 1):

That's easy!
In command, add -o option, example:

`youtube-dl -o '%(title)s%(ext)s' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XA6bS8TyN10`

In Python code, just add outtmpl option in ydl, exmaple:

`ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({
    'outtmpl': '%(title)s%(ext)s',
})
with ydl:
    ydl.download('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XA6bS8TyN10')`

for more details,read https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl#output-template